# How to disable all elements of a form in appmaker without writing code for each element?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a form in appmaker which has many (atleast 20-25) input elements.
I want to disable all of them through code without writing separate disable line code for each element.

I tried to use a for loop to do something like below but found no luck as its not right.

```
  for(var i=0; i< app.currentPage.descendants.Form1.children.length; i++) 
   {
     app.currentPage.descendants.Form1.children[0].enabled=false;
   }
```

Is there a way to disable them all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but try the following:

```
var children = app.currentPage.descendants.Form1Body.children._values;

for (var i in children) {
  children[i].enabled = false;
}
```

Note that I am using Form1Body instead of Form1 because the top Form element is made up of a header, body, and footer, so when looping over children of Form1 you are in fact referencing 3 separate panels instead of input elements.